# How to use Redis to track mobile-user-history for short term and long term

Tags: java, mobile, redis, persistence, bigdata

Our mobile app track user history (History event is predefined with action and date)

Each mobile reporting the user history and later on can retrieve it.

I though of using the latest history(let's say 100 records) on Redis for fast retrieval and after 100 records to move the old data to some datasource.

1. Do you think Redis is good for the short-term history retrieval?
2. Which datasource would you use to keep the oldest history to be ready for retrieval?

Other ideas from your experience? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Redis is great choise for the short-term history behaviour. The [LIST](http://redis.io/commands#list) is well looking data structure for that:

1. Fast insert ordered data ([LPUSH](http://redis.io/commands/lpush) for **O(1)**)
2. Fast select ([LRANGE](http://redis.io/commands/lrange) for **O(S+N)**)
3. Low memory consumption (the lowest in Redis actualy - just 21 bytes overhead per list item)

Also you may use some kind of cron job which get and insert old data to SQL like database. Use LUA scrpting to obtaine tail of logs:

```
local ret = {}
while tonumber(redis.call('llen', KEYS[1])) > tonumber(ARGV[1]) do
   table.insert(ret, redis.call('rpop', KEYS[1]))
end
return ret
```

Where KEY is your LIST key and first argument is tail size to process. This LUA script atomically cut off (and return) from all of your log entries more than ARGV[1](http://redis.io/commands#list). The next step is simple foreach by list and insert to SQL database.

While user want to get all his history (in pseudo code, there `require` variables is total records queried by user):

```
ret = redis.call('LRANGE', 'myKey', 0, require)
require = require - length(ret)
if (require > 0) {
    ret += db.query('SELECT ... LIMIT ' + require)
}
```

Comment: wouldnt use use sorted set and use the dates as scores? will be easier to get it ordered wouldnt it?

Comment: cron job which get and insert old data? how it will know to get old data from redis, and delete it..  could you elaborate on that part on your answer aswell

Comment: You are using history data, so each insert later in time than the previous. If using ZSET you would use time (unixtime?) as score for actual data. If you do not need queries with time as condition - ZSET is redundant.

Comment: Imagine the user want to retrive "oldest data" that not on Redis. How ill be able via the api to know which data source to query (redis , mysql) I need to know where data is placed

Comment: updating answer with data query example

Comment: I didnt think ill need to get into LUA scripts. not at this point. thats why I thought I could get somehow by check if records > LIMIT_VAL than take them and move them into long-term datasource(sql, etc..)

Comment: What about memory on Redis? if I keep each user tracking on Redis.. soon or later when we have million users we going to have there million records that will be stuck there.. what happen if user wasnt active for long time.. why do I need to keep it on Redis? what do you think?

Comment: I think you should transfer all old keys from Redis to sql database. Here is a little technique for that - each time you make lpush make also zadd to zset `lastUpdatedUsers`. In your cron script you would use `lastUpdatedUsers` to get list users for update data. And from time to time select all users from lastUpdatedUsers where last update time was   greate then X and move all they data to sql. So, you would keep only active user data in redis.

Comment: and as soon as 'nonupdateduser' is coming back I should re-add him to Redis? meaning that I need to re-add that user records back to Redis

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98116/discussion-between-misterion-and-rayman).